# How to fill an array with user input without specifying length of array yourself in code

Tags: c#, java, arrays, algorithm, user-input

So I'm trying to fill a char array with user input. However I do not want to specify the length of the array myself, thus limiting the user to the amount they can input. For example my code below will only allow the user to enter 5 characters and then will exit. Code in any language would be fine. (The below is C#).

```
Console.Write("Enter a number of characters of your choice...click 1 to exit: ");
bool exitCondition;
int counter = 0;
char[] character = new char[5]; 
do
{
    exitCondition = false; 
    try
    {
        character[counter] = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (character[counter] == '1')
            exitCondition = true; 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message); 
    }
    counter++;
}
while (exitCondition == false && counter < 5);
```

Comment: Please, just use the C# tag. Java!=C#

Comment: The OP specifies `Code in any language would be fine.` I think this may be to limit the bounds of code provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a collection, which allows the collection of elements to grow or shrink.  In Java an `ArrayList` would be appropriate for your scenario.  In C# you would most likely use a `List`.

**C#**

```
List<char> list = new List<char>();
list.Add('a');
list.Add('b');
```

**Java**

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
list.add('a');
```

Answer (score 3):

Array's are static in size. Use `java.util.ArrayList` ( from Collection framework) which is resizable-array.

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
chars.add('a');
chars.add('c');
chars.add('d');
```

> Resizable-array implementation of the List interface. Implements all optional list operations, and permits all elements, including null. In addition to implementing the List interface, this class provides methods to manipulate the size of the array that is used internally to store the list.

[Ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Okay, interesting, I got to read up on lists I believe. Could you post an implementation of lists to solve my problem.

Comment: @sragavan `ArrayList` is implementation of List. Its having `add` method by which you can add values to List.

Comment: As a note, if you're using Java 7 or above, you don't need to specify the extending class on both sides, and `List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();` can become: `List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();`.

Comment: @MrLore yap that is called diamond... :)

Answer (score 1):

StringBuilder is all you need

```
StringBuidler sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(c);
...
```

then you can get char array from it if you really want it

```
char[] a = sb.toString().toCharArray();
```

though typically it is just converted into a String

```
 String s = sb.toString()
```

there is also a method to work with StringBuilder internal char[] directly

```
 char c = sb.charAt(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you really want to use only array for some hidden reason :), then you can ask  user for number of input items and initialize array accordingly.

Thanks,
Naval